# Invalid # of Arguments in a stuff statement with case in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-expression

I have to do an insert into a single column/row from a source of multiple values. I'm using the stuff case and I'm so close, but I'm missing one of the expected returns, so I'm not sure what I need to do to make sure I get the results I'm looking for.

HERE is my statement:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT CASE WHEN TotalAmount <=0 THEN 'C' ELSE 'D' END FROM Charges WHERE ChargeNumber=123 FOR XML Path('')), 1,1,'')
```

The results are D D D

But, I actually have four rows, so I should see D D D D

How can I make sure that I don't delete my first return, if that's what it is doing. WHen I try 0,1 it fails.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thank you! (Running in SQL Server 2012)

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your query you don't need `STUFF()`.  Just do:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN TotalAmount <= 0 THEN 'C' ELSE 'D' END)
FROM Charges
WHERE ChargeNumber = 123
FOR XML Path('');
```

`STUFF()` is only needed when you have a separator.  It removes the separator at the beginning of the result string.  Without a separator it removes the first value, which is why you are missing one of the `'D'`s.

Comment: Dude you are awesome, I was totally over complicating it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change the 2nd 1 to a 0 it works.
For example,

```
DECLARE @Charges TABLE (ChargeNumber int, TotalAmount int)

INSERT INTO @Charges VALUES (123, 100), (123, 200), (123,100), (123, 300)

SELECT STUFF((SELECT CASE WHEN TotalAmount <=0 
                           THEN 'C' ELSE 'D' 
                     END 
               FROM @Charges 
              WHERE ChargeNumber = 123 FOR XML Path('')), 1,0,'')
```

Gives output:

```
DDDD
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I really appreciate the fast response!